# PostgreSQL: Selecting second lowest value for each unique race?

Tags: sql, postgresql, min

I have the following table using PostgreSQL

| ID | racedate | racetime | racename | track | horsename | pos | weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-1-1 | 01:00 | race1 | test | MrEd | 1 | 56 |
| 2 | 2022-1-1 | 01:00 | race1 | test | SeaBiscuit | 2 | 54 |
| 3 | 2022-1-1 | 01:00 | race1 | test | Frankel | 3 | 51 |
| 4 | 2022-1-1 | 02:00 | race2 | test | SeaRose | 1 | 57 |
| 2 | 2022-1-1 | 02:00 | race2 | test | WarAdmiral | 2 | 65 |

And so on. There are many more columns and rows of course.

Now I want to select the **second lowest value** in **weight for each race**.
So I want only one result for each unique race in the DB - How do I do that?

I tried MIN() and LEAST() in variations like

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (races.id) races.id, MIN( weight ), horses.horsename, races.racename, races.racedate, races.track
FROM horses
RIGHT JOIN races ON races.racedate = horses.racedate AND races.racetime = horses.racetime AND races.racename = horses.racename AND races.track = horses.track

WHERE weight > ( SELECT MIN( weight )
                FROM horses )
GROUP BY races.id, weight, horses.horsename, races.racename, races.racedate, races.track
ORDER BY races.id, weight
```

But this gives me the lowest value - not the second lowest.

racedate+racetime+track+racename are unique and together the primary key, I added the ID afterwards.

Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DENSE_RANK` here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT r.id, h.weight, h.horsename, r.racename, r.racedate, r.track,
           DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY r.racename ORDER BY h.weight) drnk
    FROM races r
    LEFT JOIN horses h
        ON r.racedate = h.racedate AND
           r.racetime = h.racetime AND
           r.racename = h.racename AND
           r.track = h.track
)

SELECT id, weight, horsename, racename, racedate, track
FROM cte
WHERE drnk = 2;
```

Note that `RANK()` or `ROW_NUMBER()` might also make sense here, depending on your requirements.

Comment: It's probably a bit more efficient when applying the window function before the join.

Comment: Thanks! This nearly works perfect - but it collects doubles where two horses have the same weight. Tried DISTINCT ON (r.id) r.id amd that seems to get rid of the doubles - but also some races seem to be thrown out for whatever reason by this command

Comment: @JayJericho Then you need to provide one or more additional sorting levels to break the tie and choose just one of the two duplicates.